# Error while upgrading OpenErp database?

Tags: odoo, upgrade

While migrating my database Odoo 8.0 , i am getting this error. can anyone help with this..

```
python migrate.py --config="/home/anipr/Documents/openerp-7.0/install/openerp-server.conf" --database="transtech" --run-migrations="8.0"
getting git://github.com/OpenUpgrade/OpenUpgrade.git
sh: 1: git: not found
copying database transtech to transtech_migrated...
Copying the database using 'with template'
Failed, fallback on creating empty database + loading a dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4393; 0 0 COMMENT           EXTENSION plpgsql 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
```

Thanks, Chandu

Comment: Can you provide me in detail???????????????

Comment: I have openerp 7 folder and one module in it. i want to upgrade the whole module to openerp8 for that i downloaded openupgrade module [/var/tmp/openupgrade]... then i run the script migrate.py

Comment: https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/migrate.py.html

Answer (score 0):

Following link is to migrate Odoo database from v7 to v8 step by step tutorials: [Migrate Odoo Database from version 7 to version 8](http://blogs.teckzilla.net/2015/06/09/how-to-migrate-odoo-database-from-version-7-to-version-8/)

Comment: Yeah but while coming to su postgres ... my authentication gets failure. what to do now.. i have tried some commands to to solve this issue. instead of that i type sudo su - postgres..